# How to read spaces from .txt file in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to load a sample text file with 8488 characters (including spaces) so I can then organise the words in the text file into alphabetical order in a GUI (To create a dictionary essentially).

The .txt file loads the text successfully however I can not read spaces from that file, it just shows all of the words with no spaces between

I have a class `dictionary` and within dictionary.cpp source file I attempt to load and read the text file as shown below.

```
void dictionary::loadFile(const char *fileName)
{
    char value;

    ifstream f_in(fileName);
    if (!f_in)
    {
        cerr << "\nError loading file!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File loaded successfully\n" << endl;
    }

    for  (int i = 0; i < 8488; i++)
    {
           f_in  >> value;
           Memory[i] = value;
           cout  << Memory[i];
    }
}
```

Can someone explain where I may have went wrong?

I'm quite new to working with classes, particularly in QT creator.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed.

I used

`f_in >> noskipws;`

to acknowledge the white spaces.